# How to make an image move up and down using Swift and spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using swift with xcode6 and using spritekit. I currently have a sprite jumping around moving forward but i would to have another image moving up and down constantly..

Comment: As stated in my answer : if you want a more detailed answer you should at least give it a try and post some code (what you can't achieve, what you've try, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You might want to follow those steps :

- Create another `SKSpriteNode` with the image you want
- Create a `SKAction` sequence (from two SKAction moveY)
- Run the action forever on your node

Give a look at the documentation for those two class. If more help required, please give a try and post a piece of code.